# Memory management with WPF Canvas - High number of (identical) objects

Tags: wpf, canvas, memory-management, f#

**Q: Can a WPF Canvas draw the same Child or object in several different places, or must each Child/object be unique?**

I have a WPF Canvas onto which I am drawing a high number of objects. Most of them are images of which many are identical and, as far as I know, each must be uniquely created as a Canvas *seemingly* cannot draw (or rather `Children.Add()`) an identical image in several different places (unless there is a way to do this -- which would be preferable). I am forced to do a manual `System.GC.Collect()` several times after all the objects are drawn to shrink the memory footprint back to a reasonable size (for a WPF project, at least).The memory footprint goes from around 80MB before drawing the images to around 225MB immediately after, and won't go down until `System.GC.Collect()` has been fired several times, settling back around ~80MB again.

I am also doing this programmatically in F#, and so I am not using any plain XAML whatsoever, if that makes any difference.

Comment: As you already noticed, the child elements added to a Canvas must be unique UIElements. Besides that, there is not enough information in your question to add further advice. If for example the "identical images" that are draw in "different places" would form a grid, you may perhaps put the most often used image in an ImageBrush with an appropriate TileMode.

Comment: You probably just want to do your own rendering, to avoid all that object creation. Check out, for example, https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/03/05/236-drawing-an-arbitrary-geometry-into-a-drawingvisual/.